# Displaying files and increment them +1

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm creating a script that lists all the nano files in a directory. han than the files are added with a number. (Adding +1 for every file). Then the user is allowed to view the nano file.

Here is what I have so far. I want to point out that all the filenames end with `_log` so that's why I'm hoping that the grep works like this.

```
path=~/home/folder/list

list=$(`ls $path | grep -i \*_log`)

printf '%s\n' "${list[@]}" | nl -v 1

read -p "Number of file to be displayed:" numb

sudo cat $path/${list [numb]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to make an array holding all the files and then display the contents of whichever file corresponds to the number entered by the user. If so, you are making things far more complicated than necessary. This should be enough:

```sh
## Get the files into the array $list
list=(/home/folder/list/*_log) 

## Display the file names
for i in ${!list[@]}; do 
    printf "%s: %s\n" $i "${list[i]}"; 
done
## Get the user input
read -p "Number of file to be displayed:" numb
## display the file (don't use sudo unless absolutely necessary)
cat "${list[numb]}"
```

Note that this will display the file names including the entire path. To display the names only, change the `for` loop to:

```
## Display the file names
for i in ${!list[@]}; do 
    printf "%s: %s\n" $i "${list[i]##*/}"
done
```

Comment: Still the files aren't displayed however when i type a number i can view the file as I should be. Can't figure out why it won't display all the files though.

Comment: @User101 I can't help if you don't give a specific example. I suggest you ask a new question and include the name of a file that doesn't work.